# Querying sqlite database and store the selected data into 2d array

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, 2d, querying

I am trying to query the sqlite database and store the selected data into 2d array.

My problem is that inserting "WHERE field= 'bordeaux'" into query causes error, "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExeption: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1." 
Without it, the query and array seem working well.

Also, I found that the query with "WHERE..." can show just only one appropriate record when I delete "c.moveToNext();" from the array part.

To be sure, my sqlite database contains enough data matching my query.

Sorry for my poor explanation, but I just don't understand the reason.
Could you tell me why??

My code is below.

public String[][] onQuestion(){

```
    mDbHelper = new MySQLHelper(this);
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT field, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, answer FROM WineQuiz WHERE field= 'bordeaux' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5", null);

    if(c.moveToFirst());{
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++) {
                    array[ii][0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field"));
                    array[ii][1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
                    array[ii][2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice1"));
                    array[ii][3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice2"));
                    array[ii][4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice3"));
                    array[ii][5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice4"));
                    array[ii][6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));
                    c.moveToNext();
                    }                          
        db.close();

    }
    }
        return array;
}
```

Comment: Whiy do you include (and retrieve) `field` in your query? You already know its value (`bordeaux`). And I wouldn't place the **;** here: `if(c.moveToFirst());{`. Also it appears to me that there's a **}** too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this...

```
    mDbHelper = new MySQLHelper(this);
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int cPos; // for cursor position
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT field, question, choice1, choice2, "
            + "choice3, choice4, answer FROM WineQuiz "
            + "WHERE field= 'bordeaux' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5", null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) { // If cursor has atleast one row
        String[][] array = new String[c.getCount()][7]; // Dynamic string array
        c.moveToFirst();
        do { // always prefer do while loop while you deal with database
            cPos = c.getPosition();
            array[cPos][0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field"));
            array[cPos][1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
            array[cPos][2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice1"));
            array[cPos][3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice2"));
            array[cPos][4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice3"));
            array[cPos][5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice4"));
            array[cPos][6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));
            c.moveToNext();
        } while (!c.isAfterLast());
    } else {
        Log.e("SQL Query Error", "Cursor has no data");
    }
```

Comment: it works!! Thank you very much!! I will use do while loop as your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like you're not actually returning five rows... if any. And adding a `;` after the `if` condition renders it useless. Remove that `;` to make sure you don't have an empty cursor, and check before each additional iteration that you still have records available:

```
if( c.moveToFirst() ) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < array.length && !c.isAfterLast(); ii++) {
        array[ii][0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "field"));
        array[ii][1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "question" ));
        array[ii][2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "choice1" ));
        array[ii][3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "choice2" ));
        array[ii][4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "choice3" ));
        array[ii][5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "choice4" ));
        array[ii][6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( "answer" ));
        c.moveToNext();
    }                          
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It still shows only one data. Why I can only select one data from my database?? Is there something wrong with my query??

Comment: What's in your database?

Comment: my sqlite database has 7 columns, id, field, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, answer. All of them are text except id, which is integer. The rows are 19, and 9 rows has "bordeaux" in the column of "field". I'm trying to fetch 5 rows from those 9 rows randomly.